# Is it possible to add more options to jstree after instantiate it?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have a page where i'm using `jstree` and i would like to know if it's possible to add more options after instantiate it. In that case i want to add the `dnd` plugin depending if the user loged has that role assigned.

That's how i instantiate it:

```
$treeview.jstree({

    "core" : {
        "check_callback" : function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position) {
        }
        ,"multiple":false
    }
    ,"plugins" : [ "contextmenu","state" ]
    ,"dnd": {
        copy : false
    }
    ,"contextmenu": {"items": rewriteItems}
    ,"state": { "key":$treeview }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the plugins that you need when `jstree`is going to be instantiate but exists a way that can control if the nodes are draggable or not.

Your code will look like this:

```
var isDraggable = true;
$treeview.jstree({

    "core" : {
        "check_callback" : function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position) {
    }
        ,"multiple":false
    }
    ,"plugins" : [ "contextmenu","state","dnd" ]
    ,"dnd": {
        copy : false,
        is_draggable:function() { return isDraggable; }
    }
    ,"contextmenu": {"items": rewriteItems}
    ,"state": { "key":$treeview }

});
```

You need to create a boolean variable `isDraggable` where you will keep true/false depending if the user is able to do that action. Then when you run your code and if the user is not able to drag the nodes the value will be false and he won't be able to drag it.